# Confusion about an ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let a single first-order, nonlinear ODE be defined like this: $$x'=f(x)$$ where $f$ is continuously differentiable. Suppose $f(0)=f(1)=0, f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$. Let $x(t)$ be a solution with initial value $x(0)=a\in(0,1)$, then $x'(t)>0$ for all $t$.

I don't quite get how the conclusion $x'(t)>0$ for all $t$ is obtained. May anyone explain?

Comment: Is $x(t) \in (0,1)$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is always positive in the interval $(0,1)$. Thus, also $x'(t)$ is positive in this interval, causing $x$ to monotonically increase with time towards $x=1$. You are given that $f(x=1) =0$, thus once $x$ reached 1 it stays there. Now for any initial value in the interval $(0,1)$ your initial value is clearly greater than $0$ and $x(t)$ will increase up to $1>0$.